# How to set different levels for different python log handlers

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I've read a few posts on this but I'm still confused.  I have this logging setup:

```
import logging

class MongoHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        from pymongo import Connection
        self.db = Connection('db_server').db_name

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            self.db.Logging.save(record.__dict__)
        except:
            print 'Logging Error:  Unable to save log entry to db'

mh = MongoHandler()
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger('DeviceMonitor_%s' % hostname)
log.addHandler(mh)
log.addHandler(sh)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I want to be able to set a different level for the StreamHandler and the MongoHandler.  Is that possible or do I need to have a second Logger obj?

Comment: Didn't get the selected answer to work. Used logging.Filter to only show messages of specific logging level. Colored all level messages differently for the console.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can set a different logging level for each logging handler but it seems you will have to set the logger's level to the "lowest". In the example below I set the logger to DEBUG, the stream handler to INFO and the TimedRotatingFileHandler to DEBUG. So the file has DEBUG entries and the stream outputs only INFO. You can't direct only DEBUG to one and only INFO to another handler. For that you'll need another logger.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("mylog")
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logFilePath = "my.log"
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=logFilePath, when='midnight', backupCount=30)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info("Started");
try:
    x = 14
    y = 0
    z = x / y
except Exception as ex:
    logger.error("Operation failed.")
    logger.debug(
        "Encountered {0} when trying to perform calculation.".format(ex))

logger.info("Ended");
```

Comment: I can see the limitation of this method, but actually it will work for me this time, and its a lot easier to implement..thx

Comment: Did not work for me: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'handlers'`

Comment: ifelsemonkey, import logging.handlers should bring in those missing handlers.

Comment: yep, the key for that is to set `logger` to `logging.DEBUG` level, so the handlers can filter from that levell, otherwise everything comes from `logging.WARNING` level by default.

Comment: what do you mean by "You can't direct only DEBUG to one and only INFO to another handler. For that you'll need another logger." Didn't you do that here? In a single logger?

Answer (score 13):

I needed a time to understand the point

1. Set the **general logger below** your subloggers (handlers) (your result of logging.getLogger())
2. Set your subloggers levels on **an equal or superior level** to your general logger

Comment: [This](https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2017/08/06/understanding-pythons-logging-module/) article helped me understand the logic behind this answer

Answer (score 8):

In addition to GrantVS's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111212/10323798):

I had to use

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

in order for it to work. Otherwise great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but the solution didn't work for iPython as the QtConsole automatically creates a handler with no level set:

```py
import logging                                                                                                                               
root = logging.getLogger()                                                                                                                   
root.handlers                                                                                                                                
Out: [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
```

As a result iPython printed both DEBUG and INFO to console in spite of having different levels for my file handler and stream handler.

This thread pointed out this issue for me: [Logging module does not print in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259952/logging-module-does-not-print-in-ipython)

I made a helper module (helped greatly by this stack thread!) called custom_logging.py to make logging more convenient in other modules:

```py
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import sys

def _add_stream_handler(logger: logging.Logger):

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    return logger


def _add_file_handler(logger: logging.Logger, log_path: Path):

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path, mode='w')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        fmt='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M')

    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return logger


def create_logger(root_dir: Path, caller: str) -> logging.Logger:

    log_path = root_dir / 'logs' / f'{caller}.log'
    logger = logging.getLogger(caller)
    root = logging.getLogger()

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # If haven't already launched handlers...
    if not len(logger.handlers):

        _add_file_handler(logger=logger, log_path=log_path)
        _add_stream_handler(logger=logger)

        logger.info('Logging started.')

    # Delete the Qtconsole stderr handler
    # ... as it automatically logs both DEBUG & INFO to stderr
    if root.handlers:
        root.handlers = []

    return logger


def log_dataframe(df, logger: logging.Logger, name: str = "DataFrame") -> None:

    logger.debug(
        f'''{name} head:\n {df.head()}\n----------\n''')


def log_dataframes(*args, logger: logging.Logger) -> None:

    for gdf in args:

        logger.debug(
            f'''DataFrame head:\n {gdf.head()}\n----------\n''')
```

Can use its functions via:

```py
from custom_logging import create_logger, log_dataframe
```

Or `import custom_logging` and `custom_logging.create_logger()` etc.

Also see sections 'Multiple handlers and formatters' and 'Logging to multiple destinations' in the official logging cookbook at:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook