# Logging module does not print in IPython

Tags: python, logging, ipython, qtconsole

The following code does print 'I want this to print' in 'ipython qtconsole', however it does not print in plain IPython.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

log = logging.getLogger()
f = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(module)s.   %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
fh = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('log.txt', 'W6')
fh.setFormatter(f)
log.addHandler(fh)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info('I want this to print')
```

In 'IPython qtconsole' however i get different problems, that i tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244524/printing-in-console-stopped-until-any-command-is-inserted?noredirect=1#comment37474130_24244524) (which did not go so well, no need to read!).

Can you please tell me why?

EDIT: I use Python 2.7

EDIT2: Maybe i really just need to add logging.StreamHandler.

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: You are setting a *file* handler, so the output is going to the file `log.txt`. I don't know why you think that the console should output on stdout...

Comment: This works for me: I get lines like "2014-06-17 11:39:29,422 - <ipython-input-9-ced85295bf91>. <module> - INFO - I want this to print" in log.txt.

Comment: @Bakuriu Because i set log.setLevel(logging.INFO). I was thinking, that this configures the console printing behaviour. Also in qtconsole it does print.

Comment: @Evert Which console are you using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like `qtconsole` adds an handler to the `root` logger:

```
In [1]: import logging
   ...: root = logging.getLogger()
   ...: root.handlers
   ...: 
Out[1]: [<logging.StreamHandler at 0x7fd8e00e1f98>]
```

While using the normal python interpreter or just `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: root = logging.getLogger()

In [3]: root.handlers
Out[3]: []
```

If you want both to behave the same you should either add a `StreamHandler` to the root logger for normal `ipython`, or remove the `StreamHandler` from the qtconsole interpreter.

If you want the former just add:

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

If you want the latter, *before* adding your own handler, do:

```
for handler in root.handlers[:]:
    root.removeHandler(handler)
```

---

Note that IPython already provides some machinery for logging to a file. See [the documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#session-logging-and-restoring). If you want to use the code only inside ipython using its magics might be simpler.

Comment: If you use the latter solution, it won't work properly if root has more than one handler because of removing-while-iterating problems.

Use instead:
```
while len(root.handlers):
    root.removeHandler(root.handlers[0])
```

Comment: @RonanPaixão Read the code carefully. I believe you missed 3 characters that make a difference and prevent the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me

import logger BEFORE any other library/code, in separate cell. this is actually the main requirement. If I load logging and other libraries in one cell, no matter what hierarchy in that cell is, logging does not work

```
import logging
reload(logging)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

only after loading libraries I set logging config to avoid printing pyspark load debug

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', 
                    level=logging.INFO, 
                    datefmt='%I:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I'm running Spyder3 from a Python 2.7 conda environment and this solved it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Note for those on python 3: You need to `from importlib import reload` as it is no longer a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bakuriu's latter solution, it won't work properly if root has more than one handler because of removing-while-iterating problems.

Use instead:

```
while len(root.handlers):
    root.removeHandler(root.handlers[0])
```

Comment: Bakuriu's answer does not have the problem you describe, thanks to the use of `[:]` (the 3 characters mentioned in his reply to your comment). However, your solution also works.