# Python logging set handlers to different levels

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am trying to set python logger which always writes INFO level to the stdout and at DEBUG level to a file. Something similar to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111212/3516550

but without creating another`logger` object. I tried this, but both of them get the default level of `logging.WARNING`. Is there someway for me to set both to the original `logging` object? The rest of the code uses `logging`, I'd like to preserve that, if possible.

```
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("my_log.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[file_handler, stream_handler])
```

The python version I am using is 
`Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`