# Setting different log levels for different python log handlers

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to implement a logger containing two handlers:

- a handler that sends all the log messages with `logging.INFO` severity and higher - to a log file.
- a handler that sends all the logs messages with `logging.ERROR` severity and higher - to stdout.

However, my logger writes only `logging.ERROR` level logs and above to both the file and stdout.

From looking at the [documentation's](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) handler section and a [previous question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111064/how-to-set-different-levels-for-different-python-log-handlers), it looks like I'm doing everything right - I'm setting the logger to the lowest log level and then set each handler to the level I want it to filter.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

file_logger = logging.FileHandler(filename=consts.LOGS_FILE_LOCATION)
console_logger = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

file_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
file_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(file_logger)

console_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
console_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(console_logger)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root logger always has an explicit level set (WARNING by default). Therefore it is not enough to set the level of the handlers - the level of the logger itself should be set to the lowest of the handler's levels, in my case:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```